# Animating jQuery sorted divs with CSS3

Tags: jquery, css

I'm sorting divs with jQuery and want to apply css3 transition animation to div position transitions.

Unfortunately the css3 transition animation is not working and I'm trying to figure out why:

Here is a working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfvsS/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<title>Test</title> 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<style>
.gallery {
  background-color: black;
}

.imgitem {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.imgitem {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<button id="chrank">Sort</button>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: red;"><div class="pop">6</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: blue;"><div class="pop">4</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: green;"><div class="pop">8</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: brown;"><div class="pop">1</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: magenta;"><div class="pop">3</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: grey;"><div class="pop">5</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: pink;"><div class="pop">4</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: navy;"><div class="pop">7</div></div>
  <div class="imgitem" style="background-color: yellow;"><div class="pop">9</div></div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.gallery').sortable({ disable: true });

    function doSort()
    {
        $('.gallery').sortable({ disable: true });
        $('.gallery').sortable('refresh');
        $('.gallery .imgitem').sort(sortAscending).appendTo('.gallery');
    }

    function sortAscending(a, b) {
        return $(a).find(".pop").text() > $(b).find(".pop").text() ? 1 : -1;
    };

    $("#chrank").live("click", function(){
      doSort();
    });
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, CSS transitions work. If you open dev tools and add to an `.imgitem` Element a CSS position (like `style="position: relative, top: 20px"`) you'll notice that transitions **work well!**

I Think the reason why it doesnt affect the `dvi.gallery` is because `doSort()` doesnt change the actual position of the element. It just takes all collection, sorts all by ACS and then put that *'sorted heap'* into the `dvi.gallery`

Comment: you are right, the script takes the collection, sorts it and puts it back into parent div. My expectation was that this should still result in animation because physical position of div elements in DOM is changing. What could I do to get sorting work together with animation?

Comment: @user1810414 i think in order to get CSS Animation work well, you should work with CSS position-properties (top; right, left, bottom, margins and so on)

So you need to (re)calculate the CSS position with JS and apply it to each `.imgitem` .... **BUT** it think it wont make actual sorting. The position of the elements **on the screen** will *be sorted*, but not the actual position of the elements in the DOM